# If rabbitmq can't be used as a locking service, then what can?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, distributed-system

The two main issues are:

1. Not resilient to network partitions
2. Not resilient to network failures

This article says why it can be used as a locking service: https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/02/19/distributed-semaphores-with-rabbitmq/

This article goes into more depth explaining why it can't be used as one due to the issues listed above: https://aphyr.com/posts/315-jepsen-rabbitmq

So to recap, if rabbitmq can't be used as a locking service, then what can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

- Zoo Keeper
  https://dzone.com/articles/distributed-lock-using
- Hashicorp Consul 
  https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/semaphore.html
- Azure Blobs have a lease feature that can be used
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/leader-election
- Etcd
- Any relational database. With the correct use of row locks to guarantee linearizable writes to a row you can create a distributed lock.

There are surely many more.